# Provide default value to dynamic parameters without access to the original variable-using code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is the default behavior when you give a bad variable name:

```
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>>
```

what I'm looking for is something like:

```
>>> set_name_error_handling('assign_default',None)
>>> foo
>>>
```

(`foo` is automatically assigned None)

I'm using this on dynamic parameter handling and would like to use a behavior that if the parameter is not given, a default value is being used. And I have some code that I don't have control of that have used `None` handling. Is it possible for me to just add some dynamic header like below and save the mess by not changing all other code?

```
# This may work in python2 but not python3
def foo(self,params):
    local = locals()
    for key in params:
        local[key] = params[key]
    # Do important things onwards, cannot change
```

Edit: A way to do the specific problem above, is to provide a default option, let's say:

```
options = foo.get_default_params()
# do whatsoever changes to modify options
result = foo.call(options)
```

This assumes that a default parameter table is available. Is it still doable when you don't even have the default parameter table or it's not possible to generate one (infinite possible parameters like print())?

Edit: To center the question into methodology I have rephrased the title and removed reference to override NameError.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea

Comment: This is like running VB without putting "Options Explicit" at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Yes, I think this is a terrible (development pattern wise) idea that will make errors undetectable, I just would like to know whether it is doable. A full refactoring could have been another way but it is costly.

Comment: Assigning to `locals` entries doesn't even work, as the documentation [explicitly warns about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). Why aren't you just using the `get` method of `params`, or default argument values, or a `defaultdict(lambda: None)`, or any of the much better options than what you have here?

Comment: There are definitely lots of better action if I have the control over that part of code (Or to say, I can refactor). Are there any good ways to deal with this when variables are already referenced as function parameters in old code and I can't change it but still want the benefits of a param dict?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python offers something like that. However, you could always do:

```
try:
    foo
except NameError:
    foo = None

# do whatever with foo
```

If you are trying to define a function, I would define it like this:

```
def baz_func(foo=None):
    # function body here
```

You can call this as both `baz_func()` or `baz_func(foo=5)`.

Comment: Two reasons.  1. you already have `NameError` raised by `if not foo`.  2.  Actually, what he asked for *is possible* in Python.

Comment: Understood. I edited my answer to what I originally meant to write, but I didn't know Python offered something like that. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I was asking for if "you do not know the parameter list". Is it still possible?